# The Foundry Nuke – Display an animated value on a QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qlabel, nuke

I am currently trying to display a value in a `QLabel` (`QLineEdit` would work too) based on a NUKE (or Maya) timeline.

I am using Nuke to run the code and I would like to display the value based on the current frame to display something like this:

The current frame is `1001`. If I change to frame `1002`, I would like the `QLabel` to change accordingly.

Is there a way to do that ?

```
import PySide.QtGui as QtGui
import PySide.QtCore as QtCore

def test():
    class framePanel(QtGui.QWidget):
       super(framePanel, self).__init__(self):
           layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
           self.label = QtGui.QLabel('This is frame 1001')
           layout.addWidget(self.label)

    framePanel = framePanel()
    framePanel.show()

test()
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written the following code for Mac version of The Foundry Nuke 11.2v4, so there's a `PySide2` module instead of `PySide` that is for previous versions of Nuke. Also, there are some differences touching `QtWidgets` vs `QtGui`. For getting a current frame you have to use `nuke.frame()`.

Here is the example with `QLabel`:

```
import nuke
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

def theTest():  
    class framePanel(QtWidgets.QWidget):
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel("The current frame is: %s" % nuke.frame())
        label.show()
theTest()
```

[image]

And here is an example of `QMessageBox` **with dynamically changing value**:

```
import nuke
import os.path
from PySide2 import QtGui, QtCore
from PySide2 import QtWidgets

def signalEmitter():
    qApplication = QtWidgets.QApplication.activeWindow()
    qApplication.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('wasChanged()'))

nuke.addKnobChanged(signalEmitter, nodeClass='Viewer')
qmBox = QtWidgets.QMessageBox(None)
qmBox.setText('The current frame is: %s' % nuke.frame())
qmBox.connect(QtCore.SIGNAL("wasChanged()"), lambda: qmBox.setText('The current frame is: %s' % nuke.frame()))
qmBox.setModal(False)
qmBox.show()
```

The `QMessageBox` is not `modal`.

[image]

Press on this picture to play a GIF animation!

Comment: Hi,Thanks a lot for you answer. It's basically what I am looking to do but I would like the label to change interactively. Being able to scroll the timeline and see label being update on the fly without relaunching the code. Are you aware of any way to do that ?

Comment: The second example does do what you wanted. The only problem is: this window must be selected (to be in focus). `QtCore.SIGNAL('wasChanged()')` makes the job. If this window is not selected – the value stops updating.

Comment: It works fine !  I will take some time to test that technique with LineEdit tomorrow, it should work the same way. Thanks a lot, really appreciated

Comment: Hi Again, I was just wondering if the dynamic was also possible inside a QWidget ? like in the one from your first example. I couldn't got it to work Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I didn't use a `dynamic` inside `QWidget`. Could you give me some examples to look at?

Comment: Yeah what I mean is, how can we use PySide along with a nuke parameter. Displaying the frame is an example but ideally i would like to link a nuke parameter that is animated into a QLineEdit to display the exact same value (still animated when you change frame). Sorry for the confusion. Thanks a lot for your help